# Ruby On Rails Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I've spent some time in web development and since I have decided that ruby is quite a nice language to code in I want to try the reason why some people say ruby got known : Rails

I installed rails in my linux machine however I am now trying to develop it in Windows. I know that it was recommended to install rails using RVM  in linux however I'm not sure what is the best way to install it in Windows since I've read articles which said that

```
gem install rails
```

is a method which will cause you lots of bugs in both linux and windows

My question to you is what is a method which is "bugless" to install rails in windows?
Is

```
gem install rails
```

actually buggy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, installing Rails on Windows is a little more complicated, but that's why they have bundles for it.

Go here and follow instructions.

http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: The video from the page makes all the money :D